# normalizr relational data merging with pagination

Tags: normalizr

I'm trying to create entities with relational id's. Checked the normalizr example with relational data, but when paginating, old array of post id's are replaced with new array of post id's, they're not merged.

initial entity:

```
 const entities = {
  users: {
    testUser: {
      posts: ['1', '2']
    }
  }
};
```

what happens after pagination:

```
const entities = {
  users: {
    testUser: {
      posts: ['3', '4']
    }
  }
};
```

What I expect after pagination:

```
const entities = {
  users: {
    testUser: {
      posts: ['1', '2', '3' ,'4']
    }
  }
};
```

This is code, am I missing something ? Thank you !

```
const processStrategy = (value, parent, key) => {
  switch (key) {
    case 'author':
      return { ...value, posts: [parent.id] };
    default:
      return { ...value };
  }
};

const mergeStrategy = (entityA, entityB) => {
  return {
    ...entityA,
    ...entityB,
    posts: [...(entityA.posts || []), ...(entityB.posts || [])],
  };
};

const user = new schema.Entity(
  'users',
  {},
  {
    idAttribute: 'username',
    mergeStrategy,
    processStrategy
  }
);
```